# Computing conditional PDF of multivariate function of random variables.

Tags: probability, random-variables, conditional-probability

I came across the following problem while reading a paper:

Consider two independent random variables $Y$ and $Z$ with respective marginal pdf's $p_{Z}(z)$ and $p_{Y}(y)$. Given an invertible mapping $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}^2: (y, z) \mapsto (g_1(y, z), g_2(y, z))$, let me define the random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ as:

$$X_1 = g_1(Y, Z),$$
$$X_2 = g_2(Y, Z).$$

I am interested in computing (i.e., finding a formula for) the conditional joint pdf of $X_1$ and $X_2$ given $Y$, that is:

$$p_{X_1, X_2 \,|\, Y} (x_1, x_2 \,|\, y) := \frac{p_{X_1, X_2 , Y} (x_1, x_2, y)}{p_Y(y)}.$$

I know that the joint pdf of $X_1$ and $X_2$ can be computed as:

$$p_{X_1, X_2}(x_1, x_2) = \frac{p_{Y}(y)p_{Z}(z)}{\left| \det \frac{\partial g}{\partial(y,z)} \right|} \bigg\rvert_{(y,z)=g^{-1}(x_1,x_2)},$$

where $\frac{\partial g}{\partial(y,z)}$ is the Jacobian matrix of $g$ and I have used the fact that $Y$ and $Z$ are independent.

But how about $p_{X_1, X_2 \,|\, Y}$? In the paper, they claim (without proof) that this is given by:

$$p_{X_1, X_2 \,|\, Y}(x_1, x_2 \,|\, y) = \frac{p_{Z}(z)}{\left| \det \frac{\partial g}{\partial(y,z)} \right|} \bigg\rvert_{z=f_Z(x_1,x_2)},$$

where $f_Z$ is the inverse mapping from $X_1$ and $X_2$ to $Z$.

However, this result is unintuitive for me: if $Y$ is given, then we should be able to treat it as a constant $Y=y$ from the beginning. Therefore, the result should only depend on the partial derivative $\frac{\partial g}{\partial z}$ and not on the full Jacobian matrix.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I would think the paper is wrong, but for a different (technical) reason: Conditioned on $Y=y$, the possible values of $(X_1, X_2)$ becomes $1$-dimensional -- they are the locus of the point $g(y,Z)$ as parameter $Z$ varies. So $p_{X_1, X_2 \mid Y}()$ is zero except on a $1$-D subset of the $2$-D plane, and so writing it down must require the use of Dirac delta functions; otherwise we cannot have $\forall y: \int \int p ~ dx_1 ~dx_2 = 1$ when integrating $p$ through the entire plane.  So IMHO at minimum the author is missing a Dirac delta.

Comment: I'm also very sympathetic to your argument, as intuitively conditioning on a specific $Y=y$ makes a new "law" and anything outside of $Y=y$ becomes irrelevant.  But since even the Dirac delta comes in different shapes (taller and thinner, vs shorter and fatter), I am only 99% sure about our shared intuition.  Densities can be very tricky...  It's been years since I dealt with Jacobians directly.  Maybe you can work out a simple example with uniform distributions and unequal scalings, just to create an example where you're right and the author is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Well, an answer would be that we may write the joint pdf $p_{X_1, X_2, Y} (x_1, x_2, y)$ as:

$$p_{X_1, X_2, Y} (x_1, x_2, y) =
p_{X_1, X_2}(x_1, x_2)\, \delta(y-f_Y(x_1, x_2)),$$

where $\delta$ is the Dirac function and $f_Y$ is the inverse mapping from $X_1$ and $X_2$ to $Y$.

Then, using the formula for $p_{X_1, X_2}(x_1, x_2)$ and the definition of conditional probability, the result follows. However, I still do not have an intuition for why the result depends on the derivative of $g$ with respect to $y$. And this is really puzzling me.

Comment: Maybe I'm confused, but shouldnt the joint PDF be $p_{X_1,X_2,Y}(x_1,x_2,y) = p_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2) \delta(y - f_Y(x_1,x_2))$ where $\delta()$ is the Dirac delta function?

Comment: Yes, you're correct, I'll fix it. Anyway, the basic idea is the same: the joint PDF is zero everywhere except where $y=f_Y(x_1,x_2)$. My problem persists, though.